# How can I get a count of files in a directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, centos5

How can I get a count of files in a directory using the Linux Terminal command which file has been created on current date.

Answer (score 1):

May below command will work for you.

```
find . -type f | wc -l
```

To find all files modified on the "28th Feb ,2016":

```
find . -type f -newermt 2016-02-28 ! -newermt 2016-02-29
```

Get modification from last `24hrs`.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mtime -1
```

Comment: -newermt 2016-02-28 invalid flag

Comment: @Mox: Which OS are you using?

Comment: CentOS. does it work in Ubuntu? I know it works in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need to find all files created today.

```
find . -type f -daystart | wc -l
```